# What can you do with iridium shards?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

For some reason the internet seems completely silent when it comes to the existence of iridium shards. Considering how easy it seems to be to find them and how hard it is to find iridium, I don't understand this, unless they're completely useless.

I am using MC version 1.7.10 and IC2 2.2.817

Here's a screenshot of the object I'm referencing. It looks kinda like a gray sharktooth and is labelled Iridium Shard, not ore.

[image: iridium shard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is put 9 shards into a powered compressor.  9 shards compressed will give you 1 iridium ore.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are talking about is what I think it is, it is most commonly used to be forged into Iridium Plates which is most commonly used in Quantum Armor. To read about Iridium and its uses continue reading on [THIS PAGE](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Iridium_Ore).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Check out the added image: what i've found is different from ore i think, and i can't find 'shard' actually mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Rainmaker, while the link may have good info, generally it is best practice to summarize key points to avoid info loss due to link decay.